# Hover menu in Sidebar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling how can i adjust my hover in the right side.

I have successfully hover the content i like but cant adjust the content.

This is my CSS

```
.dropdown .dropbtn {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
 }

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #1f386f;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

My HTML

```
          <div class="dropdown list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                <a class="dropbtn">
                    <b class="ps-4"><i class="bi bi-cart3 pe-4"></i> Products</b>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Products</a>
                    <a href="#">Digital</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my output

[image]

My Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dropdown{
   position:relative;
}
.dropdown-content{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:10px;
}
```

Add these two in your css file . There might be small fixes still left , you just have to change top and right values in dropdown-content , that's all .

Comment: If you find it helpful , please upvote and accept the answer , as it will help other users to find the solution to the same problem quickly .

Comment: hi do you have an idea how can i adjust this when sidebar collapsed to icon only?